# How to uri to SD card mp3 file

Tags: android, path, uri, android-sdcard, sd-card

I am trying to play an mp3 file stored in my SDcard. I am not using an emulator but a Samsung Galaxy S3 with cyanogenmod 13 android 6.0.

First I tried with

`Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/gato.mp3")`

but the

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`
 gets me to /storage/emulated/0.

With the file manager in my phone I see 3 memory storage places:

1. Internal storage is located in the /storage/emulated/0.
2. sdcard1 is
   in /storage/FE97-A11B
3. secure storage apart.

Which are different from what I see exploring from my computer (only sdcard1 and internal storage).

I couldnt make it work so I put the file "gato.mp3" in both internal and sdcard1, and I can check is there. But with

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/gato.mp3"`

which gives me the path /storage/emulated/0/gato.mp3, which should get me to the file, and also trying to set the path manually to /storage/FE97-A11B/gato.mp3, the mediaplayer created with the uri is null, and no file is found.
Same if I try the paths I see in the computer explorer.

Anybody has any idea on why it cannot find the file?
I have tried removing "/" at the beggining, adding "mnt" to see if i was missing something in the path, but nothing seem to work.

Thank you for your time!

My code to check is just a function

```
public void ejecutar(View v) {

    Uri datos = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/gato.mp3");

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, datos);

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.start();
    }
    else{ tv1.setText(datos.toString());}
```

where tv1 is a textview so i can see which path the uri is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to play an mp3 file stored in my SDcard

You do not have access to arbitrary filesystem locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

```
Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/gato.mp3")
```

Never use concatenation when assembling paths. And, I am not certain if `create(Context, Uri)` works with `file` `Uri` schemes. I recommend that you use:

```
File media=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "gato.mp3");
```

and then use `setDataSource(media.getAbsolutePath())`. You will also need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, which also means that you need to deal with [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

> but the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` gets me to `/storage/emulated/0`

That is a typical path for what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and you refer to as internal storage in your question. What the SDK refers to as internal storage is [something else](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: Ok, i see thats the main path. I have created a File media as you proposed. I print media.toString(), and indeed it poitns at /storage/emulated/0/gato.mp3, where my file is. Then I am not very sure if im doing right. I created a Mediaplayer mp = new Mediaplayer();
After I set:

    mp.setDataSource(media.getAbsolutePath())

Android Studio then need me to wrap  it in a try {} catch {}, and after i call mp.start() and nothing happens. Did I forgot to initialize something on my MediaPlayer? 
Thank you

Comment: @CommonsWare do you mind having a look at a question I posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830390/null-when-trying-to-parse-uri-from-string-path