# Null when trying to parse Uri from String path

Tags: java, android

I'm using this `FileUtils` class to handle the `Uri`:

```
public class FileUtils {
private FileUtils() {
}

private static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                    String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if (DEBUG)
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                        ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                        ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                        ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                        ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                        ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                        ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
        );

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I call it in my `MainActivity`, inside `onActivityResult`, after selecting a video from the device:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            
            //Calling FileUtils class
            String sourcePath = FileUtils.getPath(getApplicationContext(), data.getData());
          
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, PlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("videoUri", sourcePath);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            //Not relevant to the question
            .......

        }
    }
    if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to select video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

In my `PlayerActivity` I get the `String` and try to parse the `Uri`, like this:

```
//Getting String from Intent
mStringFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoUri");
//Parse Uri from String
mVideoUri = Uri.parse(mStringFilePath);
```

When testing on my device, I have no issues. I get the correct path and the `Uri.parse` works fine. But I see a lot of crashes on my Crashlytics saying - `nullpointerexception at line 59`, referring to `mVideoUri = Uri.parse(mStringFilePath);`

What am I doing wrong? Why is it working on my device and returning null on some other devices?

### Edit 1

I forgot to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in my Manifest. I'm at a point where I atleast don't get a `nullpointerexception`, but I get the following -

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not found (No such file or directory)`

Somehow the `Uri` is incorrect when I select a file from my SD Card, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

The Crash is probably occurred due to null String  on `mStringFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoUri");` since `getIntent().getStringExtras()` won't throw nullpointerexception if there isn't a value for the requested Extras but also won't give a data to the assigned variable the final result of the `mStringFilePath` will be null to fix this issue make sure that the given String for the uri parse is wrapped in:

> if(mStringFilePath != null){ mVideoUri = Uri.parse(mStringFilePath); }

Comment: Yes I know, but I would like to know why it is null. On my device I get the path and the uri as expected. Checking if it is null will not resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh the Only Current Problem I can see in this code is that there isn't handling for a non-primary volume on the device, if u have access to SD Card please try sending a file that is attached to the SD Card and see the result

Comment: if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
// Here is what i mean by handling only primary volumes
            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }

Comment: Ok I will try it and let you know. I think you are right, I don't have a SD Card in my device, that is why I don't experience the issue.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110882/get-real-path-from-uri-of-file-in-sdcard-marshmallow for Information of Implementing SD Card Storage for getting path from uri